# Word meaning (or similar to) 'able to take care of yourself'?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

What's a word (or failing that a short adjectival phrase) describing someone as being able to take care of themselves? Or something in that vicinity? Competent is somewhere in the same mile, but I'm looking for something closer ... autoresponsible would be good if it weren't made up.

An example sentence would be "There's no need to check in on Alphonse, he's X/an X kid"

Comment: You need to adjust your tags; SWR doesn't match 'short adjectival phrase'. And with a SWR, a sentence with a gap where the word is to appear is required.

Comment: OK, I've updated, thanks for the info.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

'independent'?

Merriam Webster's definition of independent is as follows:

> 1: not dependent: such as
> b(1): not requiring or relying on something else

Similar words include self-reliant, self-substaining; all kinda gearing towards 'self-' as in doing the thing by yourself (which is what I believe you are looking for..?)

Comment: Also self-sufficient.

Comment: These are good answers! As is self-sufficient from David below. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

**self-sufficient**

> 1 : able to maintain oneself or itself without outside aid : capable of providing for one’s own needs

Source: [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/self-sufficient)

Comment: That's good, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can say that they can ***fend* for themselves**:

> **fend**
> <sub>***verb***</sub>
>
> > **fend for yourself [/herself/himself/themselves]**
>
> : to take care of and provide for yourself without depending on anyone else
>
> ([Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/fend))

Answer (score 0):

***Resourceful***

[Resourceful - Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/resourceful)